# nodemailer email login invalid

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

> { [Error: Invalid login: 535 5.0.0 Authentication Failed]   code:
>   'EAUTH',   response: '535 5.0.0 Authentication Failed',
>   responseCode: 535 }

It keeps giving me this error, tried several times with different tutorials and still not working....

Also I know it will be hard to access to gmail's authentication and on top of that my gmail has two steps secure validation, so I decided to use Hotmail instead...

Here is code for my index.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    var from,name,email,subject,text;
                    $("#submit").click(function(){
                            name=$("#name").val();
                            email=$("#email").val();
                            subject=$('#subject').val();`enter code here`
                            text=$("#message").val();
                            $("#messages").text("Sending E-mail...Please wait");
                            $.get("http://localhost:8000/send",{name:name,email:email,subject:subject,text:text},function(data){
                            if(data=="sent")
                            {
                                    $("#messages").empty().html("

            Email is been sent at "+to+" . Please check inbox !

            ");
                            }

            });
                    });
            });
        </script>
```

---

below is my server.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

app.use(express.static('assets'));

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Hotmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'myemail.com',
    pass: 'something'
  }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/send', function(req, res){

  var mailOptions={
       from: "ME <my@hotmail.com>",
       name : req.query.name,
       To: req.query.email,
       subject: req.query.subject,
       text: req.query.message
   };

   console.log(mailOptions);
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
     if(error){
            console.log(error);
        res.end("error");
     }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        res.end("sent");
      }
  });
});

app.listen(8000, function(){`enter code here`
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail might block connections from unexpected geographical locations, check your account security overview to see if you need to confirm any login attempts.

Additionally, if you use 2-factor auth for Hotmail then you need application specific password for Nodemailer, you can't use your account password in this case.